# Какое число, относящееся к информатике, описано на этой странице?

Tags: алгоритм, числа

Штирлиц, находясь уже на пенсии, на полях книги записал следующую шифровку:

> сов Э и2:20 с.620

Какое число, относящееся к информатике, описано на этой странице?

Я не сильно разбираюсь , но преполагаю , что с.620 это число в 16 ричной системе счисления. Кажется так

Comment: "с.620 это число в 16 ричной системе счисления" - какое?

Comment: Полагаю, что ответ на задачу - 1024 )))

Comment: 2. Двоичная система счисления

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как версия...

1000

Потому что в то время еще приставка "кило" означала 1000. В какое время? В 1950-е годы, когда вышел 20 том второго издания БСЭ, страница 620 которого выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прошу прощения, но приставка _кило_ до сих пор обозначает именно 1000. Это только в IT-сфере распространилось общепринятое, но некорректное, понимание _кило_ как 2^10

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Ой, извините, я, понятно, не знал и искренне думал, что 1 килограмм - это 1024 грамма, километр - 1024 метра, а миллиметр - 0,0009765625 метра... Вы раскрыли мне глаза! Сейчас пойду с плакатом на улицу, чтоб об этом знали все!

Comment: я не стремился раскрыть Вам глаза, но.... "...в то время еще приставка "кило" означала 1000..." С "того времени" что-то изменилось?